# ServiceStack UpdateUserAuth RegistrationService

Tags: c#, authentication, servicestack, registration

I'm implementing my own IAuthRepository, but I can't figure out how UpdateUserAuth should be. 
the signature in IUserAuthRepository is:

```
UserAuth UpdateUserAuth(UserAuth existingUser, UserAuth newUser, string password);
```

in ServiceStack code, it's used in RegistrationService in 2 different manners:

```
UserAuthRepo.UpdateUserAuth(newUserAuth, existingUser, request.Password)
```

in UpdateUserAuth method

```
this.UserAuthRepo.UpdateUserAuth(existingUser, newUserAuth, request.Password);
```

in Post method

Is it a mistake or the desired feature?

Comment: you can see in the code itself @ https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/75847c737f9c0cd9f5dd4ea3ae1113dace56cbf2/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthRepository.cs#L22